# AWS GLUE Dynamodb - How to retain empty columns as empty when migrating data in glue

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I'm trying to migrate the data from one dynamodb table which contains two columns(`country, isMinor`) as empty for few items to another `dynamodb` table.

But after migration it puts null values in target `dynamodb` table for these two missing columns

Is there any way this is possible. Appreciate quick help on this.

Thanks in advance.

e.g. In source table:

```
 item1 = {
      "Name": {
        "S": "ABCD"
      },
      "Age": {
        "N": "10"
      }
    }
```

```
item2 = {
      "Name": {
        "S": "DEFG"
      },
      "Country": {
        "S": "XYZ"
      },
      "isMinor": {
        "BOOL": true
      },
      "Age": {
        "N": "11"
      }
    }
```

After migration it shows `item1` as:

```
 item1 = {
  "Name": {
    "S": "ABCD"
  },
  "Country": {
    "NULL": true
  },
  "isMinor": {
    "NULL": true
  },
  "Age": {
    "N": "11"
  }
```

But the expectation after migration in target `dynamodb` table is as below(same as the item in the source table):

```
item1 = {
  "Name": {
    "S": "ABCD"
  },
  "Age": {
    "N": "10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is how Glue will write the data to DynamoDB, as Glue expects a structured schema.

Depending on your type of migration, if you do not require transformation of the data you may be able to use

- [AWS Backup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/backuprestore_HowItWorksAWS.html)
- [DynamoDB Export/Import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3forDynamoDB.html)